# How should I escape strings in JSON?

Tags: java, json, escaping

When creating JSON data manually, how should I escape string fields? Should I use something like Apache Commons Lang's `StringEscapeUtilities.escapeHtml`, `StringEscapeUtilities.escapeXml`, or should I use `java.net.URLEncoder`?

The problem is that when I use `SEU.escapeHtml`, it doesn't escape quotes and when I wrap the whole string in a pair of `'`s, a malformed JSON will be generated.

Comment: If you're wrapping the whole string in a pair of `'`, you're doomed from the start: JSON strings can only be surrounded with `"`. See http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4627.txt.

Comment: +1 for the `StringEscapeUtilities` outline. Its pretty useful.

Answer (score 186, accepted):

Ideally, **find a JSON library in your language** that you can feed some appropriate data structure to, **and let it worry about how to escape things**. It'll keep you much saner. If for whatever reason you don't have a library in your language, you don't want to use one (I wouldn't suggest this¹), or you're writing a JSON library, read on.

Escape it according to the RFC. JSON is pretty liberal: The only characters you **must** escape are `\`, `"`, and control codes (anything less than U+0020).

This structure of escaping is specific to JSON. You'll need a JSON specific function. All of the escapes can be written as `\uXXXX` where `XXXX` is the UTF-16 code unit¹ for that character. There are a few shortcuts, such as `\\`, which work as well. (And they result in a smaller and clearer output.)

For full details, see [the RFC](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4627.txt).

¹JSON's escaping is built on JS, so it uses `\uXXXX`, where `XXXX` is a UTF-16 code unit. For code points outside the BMP, this means encoding surrogate pairs, which can get a bit hairy. (Or, you can just output the character directly, since JSON's encoded for is Unicode text, and allows these particular characters.)

Comment: Is it valid in JSON, like in JavaScript, to enclose strings in double quotes or single quotes? Or is it only valid to enclose them in double quotes?

Comment: @Sergei: The characters `{[]}:?` must not be escaped with a single backslash. (`\:`, for example, is not valid in a JSON string.) All of those can optionally be escaped using the `\uXXXX` syntax, at the waste of several bytes. See §2.5 of the RFC.

Comment: I'm not sure how widely it's supported, but in my experience a call to `JSON.stringify()` did the job.

Comment: For my tiny brain, the RFC is a bit vague, when it states "... any UNICODE character...". Which encoding? utf-8, utf-16, shift-jis, ...? Big endian/little endian? The RFC also does not state the character encoding for the whole json string. Some clarification would be much appreciated. Maybe for Java programmers, the term "unicode" is enough to ring a bell, but for C/C++ programmers having a std::string etc, it is not enough information.

Comment: @BitTickler: I'm not sure which part of the RFC you're referencing. If you mean what Unicode characters are valid in a string literal, then the production `unescaped` tells you what characters you can include without an escape sequence, and which must be escaped; when those two are combined, a string literal can contain any sequence of Unicode code points. String literals have no encoding: they are text. The JSON value as a whole (including embedded literals), however, *might*, if it needs to be stored as bytes; the standard mandates one of the UTF- encodings shall be used.

Comment: @LS. stringify() can change the order of non-array object properties, as cited at https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify

Comment: @Patanjali: The question and comments didn't specify order is important.  Usually, order **_should not_** be important. From json.org: "An object is an unordered set of name/value pairs." If order is important to the consumer of JSON, it should be written in a way to preserve that order.  For example, use property keys that would fall into the correct order when sorted.

Comment: @LS. Faerie's nuts. (Fair enough).

Comment: @BitTickler a unicode character is not vague at all -- it just means that it has a code point (or points) in the unicode spec. When you use std::string, it is a bunch of unicode characters.   When you need to serialize it, lets say to a file or across the network, that's where 'which encoding' comes in.  It seems according to Thanatos that they want you to use a UTF, but technically any encoding can be used as long as it can be reconstituted into unicode characters.

Answer (score 60):

Extract From [Jettison](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.codehaus.jettison/jettison/1.3.3/org/codehaus/jettison/json/JSONObject.java#JSONObject):

```
 public static String quote(String string) {
         if (string == null || string.length() == 0) {
             return "\"\"";
         }

         char         c = 0;
         int          i;
         int          len = string.length();
         StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(len + 4);
         String       t;

         sb.append('"');
         for (i = 0; i < len; i += 1) {
             c = string.charAt(i);
             switch (c) {
             case '\\':
             case '"':
                 sb.append('\\');
                 sb.append(c);
                 break;
             case '/':
 //                if (b == '<') {
                     sb.append('\\');
 //                }
                 sb.append(c);
                 break;
             case '\b':
                 sb.append("\\b");
                 break;
             case '\t':
                 sb.append("\\t");
                 break;
             case '\n':
                 sb.append("\\n");
                 break;
             case '\f':
                 sb.append("\\f");
                 break;
             case '\r':
                sb.append("\\r");
                break;
             default:
                 if (c < ' ') {
                     t = "000" + Integer.toHexString(c);
                     sb.append("\\u" + t.substring(t.length() - 4));
                 } else {
                     sb.append(c);
                 }
             }
         }
         sb.append('"');
         return sb.toString();
     }
```

Comment: Well, this was the OP tag

Comment: Don't understand only when c < ' ', change to \u.  In my case, there is character \uD38D, which is 55357 and over ' ', so doesn't change to \u...

Comment: @Stony Sounds like a new question

Comment: @MonoThreaded Thanks for your reply, I still don't know why. but finally, I changed the method to fix it like below,  
                    if (c < ' ' || c > 0x7f) {
                        t = "000" + Integer.toHexString(c).toUpperCase();
                        sb.append("\\u" + t.substring(t.length() - 4));
                    } else {
                        sb.append(c);
                    }
            }

Comment: @Stony, all characters other than `"`, `\ `, and control characters (those before “ ”) are valid inside JSON strings as long as the output encoding matches. In other words, you do not need to encode “펍” as `\uD38D` as long as the UTF encoding is preserved.

Comment: Can someone help me with the input string for the above method, which will satisfy the switch case of '/b' and /t. I am unable to write a junit for the the same. @MonoThreaded . Thanks.

Answer (score 39):

Try this `org.codehaus.jettison.json.JSONObject.quote("your string")`.

Download it here: http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.codehaus.jettison/jettison

Comment: Definitely the best solution! Thx

Comment: but this does not quoting of braces like [{

Comment: @Sergei You don't have to escape braces inside of a JSON string.

Comment: Might be useful to show what this actually returns.

Comment: org.json.JSONObject.quote("your json string") also works fine

Answer (score 26):

There is now a [StringEscapeUtils#escapeJson(String)](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-text/apidocs/org/apache/commons/text/StringEscapeUtils.html#escapeJson-java.lang.String-) method in the [Apache Commons Text](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-text/) library.

The methods of interest are as follows:

- [StringEscapeUtils#escapeJson(String)](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-text/apidocs/org/apache/commons/text/StringEscapeUtils.html#escapeJson-java.lang.String-)
- [StringEscapeUtils#unescapeJson(String)](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-text/apidocs/org/apache/commons/text/StringEscapeUtils.html#unescapeJson-java.lang.String-)

This functionality was initially released as part of [Apache Commons Lang](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/) version 3.2 but has since been deprecated and moved to [Apache Commons Text](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-text/).  So if the method is marked as deprecated in your IDE, you're importing the implementation from the wrong library (both libraries use the same class name: [StringEscapeUtils](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-text/apidocs/org/apache/commons/text/StringEscapeUtils.html)).

The implementation isn't pure Json.  As per the [Javadoc](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-text/apidocs/org/apache/commons/text/StringEscapeUtils.html#escapeJson-java.lang.String-):

> Escapes the characters in a String using Json String rules.
>
> Escapes any values it finds into their Json String form. Deals
> correctly with quotes and control-chars (tab, backslash, cr, ff, etc.)
>
> So a tab becomes the characters '\' and 't'.
>
> The only difference between Java strings and Json strings is that in
> Json, forward-slash (/) is escaped.
>
> See http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4627.txt for further details.

Comment: This is the most practical answer for me.  Most projects already use apache commons lang, so no need to add a dependency for one function.  A JSON builder would probably be the best answer.

Comment: As a follow-up, and because I can't figure out how to edit a comment I added a new one, I found javax.json.JsonObjectBuilder and javax.json.JsonWriter.  Very nice builder/writer combination.

Comment: This is deprecated in apache commons lang, you need to use apache commons **text**. Sadly, this library follows the optional/outdated spec by escaping `/` characters. This breaks lots of things including JSON with URLs in it. The original proposal had `/` as a special char to escape but this is no longer the case, as we can see in [the latest spec at time of writing](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/8.0/index.html)

Comment: @adamnfish Thank you.  I updated the answer.

Comment: I've sinced started using Google's [Gson](https://github.com/google/gson) for Json conversion.  Similarly to Apache Commons there seems to be some caveats around their implementation [[1](https://github.com/google/gson/issues/1084)] [[2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36508323/how-can-i-prevent-gson-from-converting-integers-to-doubles)] but I'm pushing on with it for now...

Answer (score 24):

org.json.simple.JSONObject.escape() escapes quotes,\, /, \r, \n, \b, \f, \t and other control characters. It can be used to escape JavaScript codes.

```
import org.json.simple.JSONObject;
String test =  JSONObject.escape("your string");
```

Comment: It depends on the json library you are using (JSONObject.escape, JSONObject.quote, ..) but it's always a static method doing the quoting job and simply should be reused

Comment: Which library is org.json part of? I don't have it on my classpath.

Comment: com.googlecode.json-simple see https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.googlecode.json-simple/json-simple/1.1.1

Answer (score 13):

`org.json.JSONObject` *`quote(String data)`* method does the job

```
import org.json.JSONObject;
String jsonEncodedString = JSONObject.quote(data);
```

Extract from the documentation:

> Encodes data as a JSON string. **This applies quotes and any necessary character escaping**. [...] Null will be interpreted as an empty string

Comment: `org.apache.sling.commons.json.JSONObject` also has this same thing

Answer (score 6):

`StringEscapeUtils.escapeJavaScript` / `StringEscapeUtils.escapeEcmaScript` should do the trick too.

Comment: `escapeJavaScript` escapes single quotes as `\'`, which is incorrect.

Answer (score 6):

If you are using fastexml jackson, you can use the following:
`com.fasterxml.jackson.core.io.JsonStringEncoder.getInstance().quoteAsString(input)`

If you are using codehaus jackson, you can use the following:
`org.codehaus.jackson.io.JsonStringEncoder.getInstance().quoteAsString(input)`

Answer (score 3):

Not sure what you mean by "creating json manually", but you can use something like gson (http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/), and that would transform your HashMap, Array, String, etc, to a JSON value. I recommend going with a framework for this.

Comment: By manually I meant not by using a JSON library like Simple JSON, Gson, or XStream.

Comment: Just a matter of curiosity -- why wouldn't you want to use one of these APIs? It's like trying to escape URLs manually, instead of using URLEncode/Decode...

Comment: Not really the same, those libraries come with a lot more than the equivalent of URLEncode/Decode, they include a whole serialization package to allow persistence of java object in json form,and sometimes your really only need to encode a short bunch of text

Comment: do a manual creating of JSON makes sense, if you wish to not include a library just for serializing small bits of data

Comment: I would ask to have a team member removed from any project I was on if they dared to create JSON manually where there existed a high quality library to do so.

Answer (score 2):

I have not spent the time to make 100% certain, but it worked for my inputs enough to be accepted by online JSON validators:

```
org.apache.velocity.tools.generic.EscapeTool.EscapeTool().java("input")
```

although it does not look any better than `org.codehaus.jettison.json.JSONObject.quote("your string")`

I simply use velocity tools in my project already - my "manual JSON" building was within a velocity template

Answer (score 2):

For those who came here looking for a command-line solution, like me, cURL's --data-urlencode works fine:

```
curl -G -v -s --data-urlencode 'query={"type" : "/music/artist"}' 'https://www.googleapis.com/freebase/v1/mqlread'
```

sends

```
GET /freebase/v1/mqlread?query=%7B%22type%22%20%3A%20%22%2Fmusic%2Fartist%22%7D HTTP/1.1
```

, for example. Larger JSON data can be put in a file and you'd use the @ syntax to specify a file to slurp in the to-be-escaped data from. For example, if

```
$ cat 1.json 
{
  "type": "/music/artist",
  "name": "The Police",
  "album": []
}
```

you'd use

```
curl -G -v -s --data-urlencode query@1.json 'https://www.googleapis.com/freebase/v1/mqlread'
```

And now, this is also a tutorial on how to query Freebase from the command line :-)

Answer (score 2):

Use EscapeUtils class in commons lang API.

```
EscapeUtils.escapeJavaScript("Your JSON string");
```

Comment: Note that single quotes for example are handled differently when escaping to javascript or json. In commons.lang 3.4 StringEscapeUtils (https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-3.4/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringEscapeUtils.html#escapeJson(java.lang.String)) has a escapeJSON method which is different than the escapeJavaScript method in commons.lang 2: https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/StringEscapeUtils.html#escapeJavaScript(java.lang.String)

Answer (score 2):

Consider [Moshi](https://github.com/square/moshi)'s [JsonWriter](http://square.github.io/moshi/com/squareup/moshi/JsonWriter.html) class. It has a wonderful API and it reduces copying to a minimum, everything can be nicely streamed to a filed, OutputStream, etc.

```
OutputStream os = ...;
JsonWriter json = new JsonWriter(Okio.buffer(Okio.sink(os)));
json.beginObject();
json.name("id").value(getId());
json.name("scores");
json.beginArray();
for (Double score : getScores()) {
  json.value(score);
}
json.endArray();
json.endObject();
```

If you want the string in hand:

```
Buffer b = new Buffer(); // okio.Buffer
JsonWriter writer = new JsonWriter(b);
//...
String jsonString = b.readUtf8();
```

Answer (score 1):

If you need to escape JSON inside JSON string, use org.json.JSONObject.quote("your json string that needs to be escaped") seem to work well

Answer (score 1):

Apache commons-text now has a 
[StringEscapeUtils.escapeJson(String)](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-text/apidocs/org/apache/commons/text/StringEscapeUtils.html#escapeJson-java.lang.String-).

Answer (score 0):

The methods here that show the actual implementation are all faulty. 
I don't have Java code, but just for the record, you could easily convert this C#-code:

Courtesy of the mono-project @ 
https://github.com/mono/mono/blob/master/mcs/class/System.Web/System.Web/HttpUtility.cs

```
public static string JavaScriptStringEncode(string value, bool addDoubleQuotes)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(value))
        return addDoubleQuotes ? "\"\"" : string.Empty;

    int len = value.Length;
    bool needEncode = false;
    char c;
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++)
    {
        c = value[i];

        if (c >= 0 && c <= 31 || c == 34 || c == 39 || c == 60 || c == 62 || c == 92)
        {
            needEncode = true;
            break;
        }
    }

    if (!needEncode)
        return addDoubleQuotes ? "\"" + value + "\"" : value;

    var sb = new System.Text.StringBuilder();
    if (addDoubleQuotes)
        sb.Append('"');

    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++)
    {
        c = value[i];
        if (c >= 0 && c <= 7 || c == 11 || c >= 14 && c <= 31 || c == 39 || c == 60 || c == 62)
            sb.AppendFormat("\\u{0:x4}", (int)c);
        else switch ((int)c)
            {
                case 8:
                    sb.Append("\\b");
                    break;

                case 9:
                    sb.Append("\\t");
                    break;

                case 10:
                    sb.Append("\\n");
                    break;

                case 12:
                    sb.Append("\\f");
                    break;

                case 13:
                    sb.Append("\\r");
                    break;

                case 34:
                    sb.Append("\\\"");
                    break;

                case 92:
                    sb.Append("\\\\");
                    break;

                default:
                    sb.Append(c);
                    break;
            }
    }

    if (addDoubleQuotes)
        sb.Append('"');

    return sb.ToString();
}
```

This can be compacted into

```
    // https://github.com/mono/mono/blob/master/mcs/class/System.Json/System.Json/JsonValue.cs
public class SimpleJSON
{

    private static  bool NeedEscape(string src, int i)
    {
        char c = src[i];
        return c < 32 || c == '"' || c == '\\'
            // Broken lead surrogate
            || (c >= '\uD800' && c <= '\uDBFF' &&
                (i == src.Length - 1 || src[i + 1] < '\uDC00' || src[i + 1] > '\uDFFF'))
            // Broken tail surrogate
            || (c >= '\uDC00' && c <= '\uDFFF' &&
                (i == 0 || src[i - 1] < '\uD800' || src[i - 1] > '\uDBFF'))
            // To produce valid JavaScript
            || c == '\u2028' || c == '\u2029'
            // Escape "</" for <script> tags
            || (c == '/' && i > 0 && src[i - 1] == '<');
    }



    public static string EscapeString(string src)
    {
        System.Text.StringBuilder sb = new System.Text.StringBuilder();

        int start = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < src.Length; i++)
            if (NeedEscape(src, i))
            {
                sb.Append(src, start, i - start);
                switch (src[i])
                {
                    case '\b': sb.Append("\\b"); break;
                    case '\f': sb.Append("\\f"); break;
                    case '\n': sb.Append("\\n"); break;
                    case '\r': sb.Append("\\r"); break;
                    case '\t': sb.Append("\\t"); break;
                    case '\"': sb.Append("\\\""); break;
                    case '\\': sb.Append("\\\\"); break;
                    case '/': sb.Append("\\/"); break;
                    default:
                        sb.Append("\\u");
                        sb.Append(((int)src[i]).ToString("x04"));
                        break;
                }
                start = i + 1;
            }
        sb.Append(src, start, src.Length - start);
        return sb.ToString();
    }
}
```

Comment: How is the `quote()` method described in other answers faulty?

Answer (score 0):

using the \uXXXX syntax can solve this problem, google UTF-16 with the name of the sign, you can find out XXXX, for example:utf-16 double quote

Answer (score 0):

I think the best answer in 2017 is to use the javax.json APIs.  Use javax.json.JsonBuilderFactory to create your json objects, then write the objects out using javax.json.JsonWriterFactory.  Very nice builder/writer combination.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want a manual one-off solution to escape some text on the fly and are using a Windows machine, this PowerShell solution will work from a clean install of the OS with no other tools:

```
[PSCustomObject] @{
   'foo' = 'Hello, World!'
   'bar' = 'Goodbye, World!'
} | ConvertTo-JSON
```

Result:

```
{
    "foo":  "Hello, World!",
    "bar":  "Goodbye, World!"
}
```

If you're not familiar with PowerShell, these single quotes work like UNIX hard quotes; the only escape you'll need is for more sinqle quotes. Double quotes are often more convenient if your data has single quotes, but certain characters will need to be escaped with back ticks:

```
[PSCustomObject] @{
   'foo' = 'two single quotes: '''' and two dollar signs: $$'
   'bar' = "two single quotes: '' and two dollar signs: `$`$"
} | ConvertTo-JSON
```

Result:

```
{
    "foo":  "two single quotes: \u0027\u0027 and two dollar signs: $$",
    "bar":  "two single quotes: \u0027\u0027 and two dollar signs: $$"
}
```

Piping to clip.exe will output the result to your clipboard so you can paste it somewhere else:

```
[PSCustomObject] @{
   'foo' = 'some quotes: """'
   'bar' = 'picket fence: /\/\/\'
} | ConvertTo-JSON | clip
```

No result is displayed, but this is now in the user's clipboard:

```
{
    "foo":  "some quotes: \"\"\"",
    "bar":  "picket fence: /\\/\\/\\"
}
```