# how to make Json lib generate such string: \/Date(1317375052044)\/

Tags: java, json, json-lib

My target is to generate such json string: `{"EndTime": "\/Date(1309737600000)\/"}`

I define a HashMap to generate the string

If I define the string value as `"\\/Date(1317375052044)\\/"` then the result is `"\\\\/Date(1317375052044)\\\\/"`.

If I define the string as `"/Date(1317375052044)/"` then the result is `"/Date(1317375052044)/"`.

How I can generate the result `"\/Date(1309737600000)\/"`?

Answer (score 0):

Duplicated from [How should I escape strings in JSON?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3020094/1290442) . Following this response try defining the string as `"\\\\/Date(1317375052044)\\\\/"` because in Java String '\' is also a escape character!