# Putting quotation marks in Sublime Text configuration files

Tags: windows, cmd, sublimetext2, sublimetext

I am trying to Run java class file with the new cmd window.
But i want to add the pause command at finish to view the result, so i edit the file `JavaC.sublime-build` like this:

```
{
"cmd": ["javac", "${file}"],
"working_dir": "${file_path}",
"selector": "source.java",
"shell": true,
"variants":
[
    {
        "name": "Run",
        "cmd": ["start cmd /c", ""java ${file_base_name} & pause""]
    }
]
}
```

But it doesn't work, the `"cmd": ["start cmd /c", ""java ${file_base_name} & pause""]` mean i wanna process the command `start cmd /c "java ${file_base_name} & pause"` but sublime-text doesn't understand `""`.

Anyone can solve this?

Comment: what happens if you just have single quotes - `"cmd": ["start cmd /c", "java ${file_base_name} & pause"]`

Comment: Escape them with backslash. Which means write \" instead of "

Comment: @MattDMo It will run but close instant because `pause` command is ignore.

Comment: @T-- it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sublime Text configuration files are [JSON](http://json.org) format.

JSON string escape rules can be read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3020094/how-should-i-escape-strings-in-json)

Example escape:

```
'{"a":5,"b":"a \\"kitty\\" mighty odd"}'
```