# Java escape JSON String?

Tags: java, json, node.js

I have the following JSON string that i am sending to a NodeJS server:

```
String string = "{\"id\":\"" + userID + "\",\"type\":\"" + methoden + "\",\"msg\":\"" + msget + "\", \"name\":\"" + namnet + "\", \"channel\":\"" + activeChatChannel + "\", \"visitorNick\":\"\", \"agentID\":\" " + agentID + "\"}";

PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(os, "utf-8"));
pw.println(string);
```

The problem becomes when the string `msget` contains the character `"` and `'`

On the NodeJS server i am parsing the JSON like this:

```
var obj = JSON.parse(message);
```

Any ideas how i can manage to send all characters without problems?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34427279/how-do-i-pass-this-escaped-json-with-gson-java

Answer (score 31, accepted):

I would use a library to create your JSON `String` for you. Some options are:

- [GSON](http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/)
- [Crockford's lib](http://www.json.org/javadoc/org/json/package-summary.html)

This will make dealing with escaping much easier. An example (using `org.json`) would be:

```
JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();

obj.put("id", userID);
obj.put("type", methoden);
obj.put("msg", msget);

// etc.

final String json = obj.toString(); // <-- JSON string
```

Comment: what if I don't want a builder and just the value string not the entire json?

Answer (score 24):

The JSON specification at https://www.json.org/ is very simple by design. Escaping characters in JSON strings is not hard.  This code works for me:

```
private String escape(String raw) {
    String escaped = raw;
    escaped = escaped.replace("\\", "\\\\");
    escaped = escaped.replace("\"", "\\\"");
    escaped = escaped.replace("\b", "\\b");
    escaped = escaped.replace("\f", "\\f");
    escaped = escaped.replace("\n", "\\n");
    escaped = escaped.replace("\r", "\\r");
    escaped = escaped.replace("\t", "\\t");
    // TODO: escape other non-printing characters using uXXXX notation
    return escaped;
}
```

Answer (score 23):

### Apache Commons

If you're already using Apache commons, it provides a static method for this:

```java
StringEscapeUtils.escapeJson("some string")
```

It converts any string into one that's properly escaped for inclusion in JSON

[See the documentation here](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-text/javadocs/api-release/org/apache/commons/text/StringEscapeUtils.html)

Comment: it is deprecated

Answer (score 18):

`org.json.simple.JSONObject.escape()` escapes quotes,, /, \r, \n, \b, \f, \t and other control characters.

```
import org.json.simple.JSONValue;
JSONValue.escape("test string");
```

- [`json-simple` home](https://code.google.com/archive/p/json-simple/)
- [document](http://juliusdavies.ca/json-simple-1.1.1-javadocs/org/json/simple/JSONValue.html#escape(java.lang.String))

Add pom.xml when using maven

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.googlecode.json-simple</groupId>
    <artifactId>json-simple</artifactId>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

Comment: There is no such method `escape`.

Comment: [doc](http://alex-public-doc.s3.amazonaws.com/json_simple-1.1/org/json/simple/JSONObject.html#escape(java.lang.String))

Comment: See Java JSONObject doc: http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/json/JsonObject.html

Comment: Not java jsonObject. Look `import` in code. 
json-simple: https://code.google.com/archive/p/json-simple/

Comment: JSONObject.quote(String) does the job.

Comment: JSONObject.quote(String) does the job but adds extra " around the string

Comment: maven repository doesn't exist please remove this answer.

Answer (score 12):

The best method would be using some JSON library, e.g. Jackson ( http://jackson.codehaus.org ).

But if this is not an option simply escape msget before adding it to your string:

The wrong way to do this is

```
String msgetEscaped = msget.replaceAll("\"", "\\\"");
```

Either use (as recommended in the comments)

```
String msgetEscaped = msget.replace("\"", "\\\"");
```

or

```
String msgetEscaped = msget.replaceAll("\"", "\\\\\"");
```

A sample with all three variants can be found here: http://ideone.com/Nt1XzO

Comment: I didn't downvote, but the `replaceAll()` won't work. You need to use `replace`.

Comment: Have you tried the code you posted? It has no effect. Either you use `replace(...)` or `replaceAll("\"", "\\\\\"")`, because the backslash has a special meaning in the replacement string, too. See javadoc.

Comment: I'm biased if i should delete this answer because it's wrong or if i should let it as is 'cause it shows how not to do it?

Comment: @DirkLachowski: If I were you, I'd either delete it (when I'm feeling lazy) or fix it.

Comment: @jlordo: I'm afraid you are wrong. The difference between replace() and replaceAll() is that in the former the first arg is a literal string and in the later it's a regex. The replacement is no regex (but can contain some special chars  in the later). So replaceAll() will work as posted by me - and yes, i've tried it now.

Comment: @DirkLachowski: You're right that `replace()` takes a literal and `replaceAll()` takes a regex. But if you use `replaceAll()` you have to use it as I posted in my comment. See http://ideone.com/XhDeaT Yours won't work.

Comment: @jlordo: Thumbs up for getting back on this and for the link to idone.com. Didn't knowed that before. I got it now, thanks for the lesson.

Comment: @DirkLachowski: removed my -1, as the answer is now correct ;)

Answer (score 4):

According to the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3020094/how-should-i-escape-strings-in-json), quotes in values need to be escaped. You can do that with `\"`

So just repalce the quote in your values

```
msget = msget.replace("\"", "\\\"");
```

Answer (score 4):

If you want to simply escape a string, not an object or array, use this:

```
String escaped = JSONObject.valueToString(" Quotes \" ' ' \" ");
```

http://www.json.org/javadoc/org/json/JSONObject.html#valueToString(java.lang.Object)

Comment: The link is broken, here is a web-archive version of it: https://web.archive.org/web/20151006021420/http://www.json.org/javadoc/org/json/JSONObject.html

Answer (score 3):

```
public static String ecapse(String jsString) {
    jsString = jsString.replace("\\", "\\\\");
    jsString = jsString.replace("\"", "\\\"");
    jsString = jsString.replace("\b", "\\b");
    jsString = jsString.replace("\f", "\\f");
    jsString = jsString.replace("\n", "\\n");
    jsString = jsString.replace("\r", "\\r");
    jsString = jsString.replace("\t", "\\t");
    jsString = jsString.replace("/", "\\/");
    return jsString;
}
```

Comment: It's Work for me... Great Solution.

Answer (score 2):

In `build.gradle` (if using maven, make similar change) include this dependency:

```
implementation group: 'org.apache.avro', name: 'avro-tools', version: '1.10.2'
```

Then:

```
import net.minidev.json.JSONValue;
String escapedString = JSONValue.escape(yourString);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do it yourself without any library, you can use this piece of Java code:

```
/**
 * Escapes a string the JSON way.
 *
 * @param text The text to be escaped.
 * @return a string escaped according to the JSON format.
 */
public static String escape(final CharSequence text) {

    if (text == null) {
        return "";
    }
    final StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
    for (int i = 0, length = text.length(); i < length; i++) {
        final char c = text.charAt(i);
        switch (c) {
            case '"':
                writer.write("\\\"");
                break;
            case '\\':
                writer.write("\\\\");
                break;
            default:
                if (c > 0x1f) {
                    writer.write(c);
                } else {
                    writer.write("\\u");
                    final String hex = "000" + Integer.toHexString(c);
                    writer.write(hex.substring(hex.length() - 4));
                }
        }
    }
    return writer.toString();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you can use slightly more modern Java and don't want another dependency, this does the job:

```java
    static String jsonStringQuote(String string) {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("\"");
        for (char c : string.toCharArray())
            sb.append(switch (c) {
                case '\\', '"', '/' -> "\\"+c;
                case '\b' -> "\\b";
                case '\t' -> "\\t";
                case '\n' -> "\\n";
                case '\f' -> "\\f";
                case '\r' -> "\\r";
                default -> c < ' ' ? String.format("\\u%04x", c) : c;
            });
        return sb.append('"').toString();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

On Android (and `org.json`), you could use [JSONObject.quote](https://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONObject#quote(java.lang.String)).

```
import org.json.JSONObject;
String stringifiedString = JSONObject.quote(data);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to replace all the " and ' with a \ before them. Do this just for the msget object(String, I guess). Don't forget that \ must be escaped too.

Answer (score 0):

Consider [Moshi](https://github.com/square/moshi)'s [JsonWriter](https://square.github.io/moshi/1.x/moshi/com/squareup/moshi/JsonWriter.html) class ([source](https://github.com/square/moshi/blob/bf72ce8ade0db490136834096e0881d17c87e20a/moshi/src/main/java/com/squareup/moshi/JsonWriter.java)). It has a wonderful API and it reduces copying to a minimum, everything is nicely streamed to the OutputStream.

```
OutputStream os = ...;
JsonWriter json = new JsonWriter(Okio.sink(os));
json
  .beginObject()
  .name("id").value(userID)
  .name("type").value(methodn)
  ...
  .endObject();
```