# Message contains escape character in the message sent to MQ and cause exception when converting to JSON

Tags: java, spring-boot, jms, ibm-mq

I have a method:

```
public void sendMessage(MyJobDTO myJobDTO) {
    jmsTemplate.send(new MessageCreator() {

        public Message createMessage(Session session) throws JMSException {

            TextMessage message = null;
                message = session.createTextMessage(myJobDTO.toString());
                logger.info("Sending message...");
                logger.info(message);
            

            return message;
        }
    });
    
}
```

and my DTO's toString():

```
@Override
public String toString() {
    return "{" +
            "\"A\":" + "\"" + prop_a + "\"," +
            "\"B\":" + "\"" + prop_b + "\"," +
            "\"C\":" + "\"" + prop_c + "\"" +
            "}";
}
```

I realise when the other application received the MQ message (using Spring Boot with JMS), the escape char `\` appeared, causing errors. I tried to do `replaceAll("\\\\", "")` but it couldnt find anything to replace. How can I get rid of the `\` in the message sent to the MQ?

Comment: could you show us the received message

Comment: also maybe try .replace("\\\"", "\""); instead

Comment: what does the receiving end's code look like

Comment: Need to deal wtih a few more characters too as shown in this previous answer to a similar Q  - https://stackoverflow.com/a/50522874  for all the `prop_X` values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The clean way to handle this is to use a proper JSON library to create the JSON string.  For example, using the `org.json` library ([javadoc](https://stleary.github.io/JSON-java/org/json/JSONObject.html)).

```
public String toString() 
    JSONObject jo = new JSONObject();
    jo.put("A", propA);
    jo.put("B", propB);
    jo.put("C", propC);
    return jo.toString();
}
```

This will escape the values in `propA` etcetera if this is necessary.  The result will be well-formed JSON.

Comment: thanks a lot!  By any chance you know how I can fix the same problem if I need to return an XML instead of JSON?

Comment: I believe that there are APIs for doing the equivalent, but I'm not that familiar with them.  There should be other existing Q&As that explain.