# Parse JSON with Quotes and Slash Java

Tags: java, json, spring, spring-boot

I am calling a server that's giving giving 400 bad request error with below body.

```
org.springframework.web.client.HttpClientErrorException$BadRequest: 400 Bad Request: \"{<EOL>??\"headerRecordError\": [<EOL>???{<EOL>?            ?\"host\": \"3\"<EOL>?            ?, \"version\": \"00\"<EOL>?            ?, \"surName\": \"TEST    \"<EOL>?????, \"firstName\": \"TEST\"<EOL>?            ?,<EOL>?            \dDate\": \"11092021\"<EOL>???}<EOL>??],<EOL>     \"errors\": [<EOL> <EOL>??      {<EOL>??        \"errorCode\": \"006\",<EOL>??        \"errorType\": \"Api Validation\",<EOL>??        \"message\": \"Invalid stream error\"<EOL>??      }<EOL>??      ,{<EOL>??        \"errorCode\": \"006\",<EOL>??        \"errorType\": \"Some Error\", \"Items\": \"000\"<EOL>????}<EOL>???]<EOL>   <EOL>}\"", "logType": "Normal", "loggerName": "com.testapp", "uniqueRequestId": null}
```

I know I can use delimiters to split and extract the information but I want to know if there's a better way. Is there a library or a cleaner way if I want to extract any specific field from this payload such as *errorCode* or *message.*

Comment: Spiting or any string operation is the wrong way to get the value. You have a JSON document inside a JSON string. You should use a JSON library to read the value and convert it. See the accepted answer on [Java escape JSON String?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18898773/java-escape-json-string)

Comment: Usually 400 Bad Request mean your request payload is invalid, Can you add sample of the JSON request you send to this server and not the response that the service returns?  What Http Client library are you using? can you add sample of the code you use to call this service?