# Escape JSON string in Java

Tags: java, json, jackson

I'm using Google's `com.google.api.client.json.GenericJson` and `com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonGenerator`. I would like to serialize JSON object and escape quotes and backslashes so that I can pass that string in Bash. And afterwards deserialize that string.

`GenericJson.toString` produces simple JSON, but `\n` etc. are not escaped:

```
{commands=ls -laF\ndu -h, id=0, timeout=0}
```

is there a simple way how to get something like this:

```
"{commands=\"ls -laF\\ndu -h\", id=0, timeout=0}"
```

I don't want to reinvent the wheel, so I'd like to use Jackson or an existing API, if possible.

Comment: You might be looking for [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16652683/1066946)

Comment: I was trying to avoid writing it from scratch, there's also Apache Commons method to escape JavaScript: http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/StringEscapeUtils.html#escapeJavaScript(java.lang.String)

Comment: Stick the serialized JSON into an array and run it through the serializer a second time, then strip off the `[]` characters.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

No additional dependencies needed: You're looking for `JsonStringEncoder#quoteAsString(String)`.

Click for [JsonStringEncoder javadoc](http://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-core/javadoc/2.1.0/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/io/JsonStringEncoder.html)

### Example:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.io.JsonStringEncoder;

JsonStringEncoder e = JsonStringEncoder.getInstance();
String commands = "ls -laF\\ndu -h";
String encCommands = new String(e.quoteAsString(commands));
String o = "{commands: \"" + encCommands + "\", id: 0, timeout: 0}"
```

Ref: http://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-core/javadoc/2.1.0/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/io/JsonStringEncoder.html

Comment: I think you mean "quoteAsString" instead of "quoteAsJson" in that first code block?

Comment: Well, the example he gave was a Json block. But yeah, one of those.

Answer (score 5):

Using `Gson` for serialization proved to be quite easy and bulletproof. Afterwards Apache's `commons-lang3 = 3.1` `escapeEcmaScript` is used. In `3.2` there's also `escapeJson` method.

```java
import com.google.api.client.json.GenericJson;
import com.google.api.client.util.Key;
import com.google.gson.Gson;
import org.apache.commons.lang3.StringEscapeUtils;

public class MyJson extends GenericJson {

    @Key("commands")
    public String commands;

    public String serialize() throws IOException {
      Gson gson = new Gson();
      String g = gson.toJson(this);
      return StringEscapeUtils.escapeEcmaScript(g);
    }
}
```

This produces escaped JSON:

```
{\"commands\":\"ls -laF\\ndu -h\"}
```

Deserialization is then quite simple:

```
protected MyJson deserialize(String str) throws IOException {
    String json = StringEscapeUtils.unescapeEcmaScript(str);
    JsonObjectParser parser = (new JacksonFactory()).createJsonObjectParser();
    return parser.parseAndClose(new StringReader(json), MyJson.class);
}
```

The `escapeEcmaScript` method isn't complicated, it does following replacement:

```
  {"'", "\\'"},
  {"\"", "\\\""},
  {"\\", "\\\\"},
  {"/", "\\/"}
```

But at least is something I don't have to care about.

Comment: escapeJson  is accessed from StringEscapeUtils() and this is deprecated now .