# How can I encode JSON object content into a JSON string?

Tags: java, json, gson

Trying to find a way to stringify a JSON string, with escape characters like JavaScript.

For example --

**Input:**

```
{"name":"Error","message":"hello"}
```

**Output:**

```
"{\"name\":\"Error\",\"message\":\"hello\"}"
```

I am able to get the object as JSON String using Gson, but not stringify (with escape characters).

Is this possible with Java?

Comment: ``strJson.replace("\"","\\\"");`` ?

Comment: https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringEscapeUtils.html#escapeJson-java.lang.String-

Comment: @RobinTopper That's close to what I am looking for. But Jackson's JsonStringEncoder.quoteAsString() feels like a better alternative for me, as it can correct formatting of JSON as well.

Comment: Jackson's JsonStringEncoder.quoteAsString() Example:  http://stackoverflow.com/a/40430760/639107

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your input is a JSON object as text, presumably stored in a `String`. You're essentially trying to convert that *text* to a JSON string. So do just that.

```
String input = "{\"name\":\"Error\",\"message\":\"hello\"}";
System.out.println("Original JSON content: " + input);
Gson gson = new Gson();
String jsonified = gson.toJson(input);
System.out.println("JSONified: " + jsonified);
```

Since quotes (and other characters) must be escaped in JSON strings, the `toJson` will properly perform that transformation.

The code above will produce the

```
Original JSON content: {"name":"Error","message":"hello"}
JSONified: "{\"name\":\"Error\",\"message\":\"hello\"}"
```

In other words, `jsonified` now contains the content of a JSON string.

With Jackson, the process is the same, just serialize the `String` instance that contains your JSON object text

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
mapper.writeValue(writer, input);
jsonified = writer.toString();
System.out.println("JSONified: " + jsonified);
```

produces

```
JSONified: "{\"name\":\"Error\",\"message\":\"hello\"}"
```

Answer (score 1):

Another solution, I noted in comments:

Jackson's JsonStringEncoder.quoteAsString() Example: [stackoverflow.com/a/40430760/639107](http://stackoverflow.com/a/40430760/639107)

Answer (score 0):

You can try this on your output json string :

```
String strWithEscChar = output.replaceAll("\"", "\\\\\"");
```