# java String replaceAll " to \\"

Tags: java, replaceall

I want to replace " in my string to \\" for later use by Javascript JSON.parse(...), I try the following test

```
String name = "\"ab\"c";
System.out.println("name before escape="+name);
String name1 = name.replaceAll("\"", "\\\"");
System.out.println("name1="+name1);
String name2 = name.replaceAll("\"", "\\\\\"");
System.out.println("name2="+name2);
String name3 = name.replaceAll("\"", "\\\\\\\"");
System.out.println("name3="+name3);
```

and result as follow:

```
name before escape="ab"c
name1="ab"c
name2=\"ab\"c
name3=\"ab\"c
```

so all fail, and I don't understand the output result

1. why name2 and name3 are the same?
2. how to replace all " to \\"

[Update1}

for question 2, I found the following work

```
System.out.println("name4=" + name.replaceAll("\"", Matcher.quoteReplacement("\\\\\"")));
```

Although I feel lost for the reason it works...

Comment: Don't construct your own JSON. Use a library. We get plenty of JavaScript questions here on Stack Overflow that ask how to fix malformed JSON (which is often near to impossible) because the source they got it from didn't encode it correctly. Don't make that mistake.

Comment: Also, what is your exact desired output?

Comment: @ivar any library recommended?

Comment: @OlivierGrégoire my desired output is \\"ab\\"c

Comment: You can use Jackson, Gson or JSON-java. If you only want to encode one string, then you can use it [as shown here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21576475/escape-json-string-in-java/40430760). But if it is part of a bigger JSON, then you can also [convert a complete POJO into JSON](https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-object-mapper-tutorial).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use replaceAll need to escape \ and "

```java
String name = "\"ab\"c";
System.out.println("name before escape="+name);
String name1 = name.replaceAll("\\\"", "\\\\\\\\\"");
System.out.println("name1="+name1);
```

Comment: No, this output name1=\"ab\"c, NOT \\"ab\\"c

Comment: just update the answer, name.replaceAll("\\\"", "\\\\\\\\\"")

Comment: but can explain why this work? there is 9 backslash, the first three \\\, as \ has special meaning in java and regex, so one  backslash need add two more backslash to esapce, so from left to right, the first six backslash output \\, but how to explain the remaining 7th, 8th, 9th backslash plus the double quote \\\"   ?

Comment: 2 escape in string and regex string. string defination "\\\\\\\\\"", \\ -> \, \" -> ",  so raw string is\\\\". in regex string also need escape, so \\ -> \, \" -> ", so it's \\"

Comment: first is java escape, so 1st, 2nd backslash means one backslash, 3rd, 4th the second, 5th, 6th the third, 7th, 8th the fourth, remaining \", means ", so the raw string is four backslash plus one double quotes \\\\"
then in regex expression, first backslash and second backslash output one backslash, 3rd, 4th backslash output the second backslash, so becomses \\"
Do you mean this?

Comment: yep, that's what I mean

Comment: Ask for more, Java escape is always interpret first before regex escape?

Comment: yes, this is firstly a java string literal, so java escape is always interpreted first

Answer (score 2):

It's better to use `replace()` instead of `replaceAll()`:

```
String name = "\"ab\"c";
System.out.println("name before escape=" + name);
System.out.println("name1=" + name.replace("\"", "\\\\\""));
```

**Output:**

```
name before escape="ab"c
name1=\\"ab\\"c
```

Comment: but if I want to use replaceAll, then how to write? and how to interpret the result of name1, name2 and name3 in my question?

Answer (score 1):

Don't use `replaceAll`, use `replace`: `name.replace("\"", "\\\"");` The reason is that `replaceAll` uses regex and it can mess all your formatting up.

```java
class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    String name = "\"ab\"c";
    String name1 = name.replace("\"", "\\\\\"");
    System.out.println(name1); // Prints: \\"ab\\"c
  }
}
```