# How to stop Java from separating JSON string passed as a command line argument into separate subunits of args[]

Tags: java, json, command-line-arguments, spaces, args

I want to pass this JSON String to a Java class through command line arguments.

> {"body": "We should definitely meet up, man", "startDate": "2014-05-29 11:00:00", "endDate": "2014-05-29 12:00:00", "location": "Boca Raton", "subject": "This is the subject of our meeting."}

However, at every space, the String gets split up. So args[0] is

> {"body":

args[1] is

> "We

etc.

I want args[0] to just be

> {"body": "We should definitely meet up, man", "startDate": "2014-05-29 11:00:00", "endDate": "2014-05-29 12:00:00", "location": "Boca Raton", "subject": "This is the subject of our meeting."}

I tried using double quotes, but since there are quotes in the JSON string it didn't work.

How can I do this? Thanks so much!

Comment: It's not Java doing that, it's the Windows/whatever command processor.

Comment: You have to escape the json: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3020094/how-should-i-escape-strings-in-json

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here is a better solution:

1. Stop passing json as a command line argument.
2. Put the json in a file.
3. Pass the name of the json file as a command line argument.
4. Read the json file in your application.

Comment: Your solution may be a better approach, but the performances are reduced, since you're doing 2 system calls to write/read a file.

Comment: Passing a file is much more complicated, if not impossible in certain cases, when dealing with an automation of java application execution.

Answer (score 4):

You need to escape the double-quote characters and surround the entire String with normal double-quotes:

```
java Test "{\"body\": \"We should definitely meet up, man\", \"startDate\": \"2014-05-29 11:00:00\", \"endDate\": \"2014-05-29 12:00:00\", \"location\": \"Boca Raton\", \"subject\": \"This is the subject of our meeting.\"}"
```

This is a Windows example.

Comment: Simple yet powerful answer.

Answer (score 2):

This isn't a Java issue: it's a shell issue. So the answer depends on what shell you're using.

If you're on a UNIX-y shell, try putting the JSON within single quotes. For instance: `java my.MainClass '{ "key1": "value1" }'`. That'll probably work on Windows, too ... I'm not sure.

If you have a `'` in your JSON, things get complicated. If your shell is Bash, one option is to replace every `'` with `'\''`.

But where is the JSON coming from? If you're actually invoking this Java program from within another program, you can skip the shell altogether. Python's `subprocess.call`, Ruby's `IO.popen`, Bash's `"$@"` and Java's `ProcessBuilder` all accept an array of command-line arguments instead of a single-string command. Alternatively, logic like Ruby's `Shellwords` exists for just about any programming language and quotes command-line parameters so the shell parses them into exactly the bytes you specify.

Another alternative: you can pipe the JSON to your program. Invoke it like this (on UNIX):

```
cat | java my.MainClass
{
  "you can just type": "this stuff",
  "and it will eventually get picked up by": "Java"
}
[Ctrl-d (UNIX) or Ctrl-z (Windows)]
```

And read it in Java as discussed at [Read/convert an InputStream to a String](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/309424/read-convert-an-inputstream-to-a-string) -- using `System.in` as the `InputStream`.

Comment: I'm invoking the Java program from a Python program. How do I use subprocess.call?

Comment: @adam-hopper It worked for me thanks for suggest single quote suggestion for bash shell.

Answer (score 1):

Try to encode your JSON string in base64:

> {"body": "We should definitely meet up, man", "startDate": "2014-05-29
> 11:00:00", "endDate": "2014-05-29 12:00:00", "location": "Boca Raton",
> "subject": "This is the subject of our meeting."}

will be encoded to

> eyJib2R5IjogIldlIHNob3VsZCBkZWZpbml0ZWx5IG1lZXQgdXAsIG1hbiIsICJzdGFydERhdGUiOiAiMjAxNC0wNS0yOSAxMTowMDowMCIsICJlbmREYXRlIjogIjIwMTQtMDUtMjkgMTI6MDA6MDAiLCAibG9jYXRpb24iOiAiQm9jYSBSYXRvbiIsICJzdWJqZWN0IjogIlRoaXMgaXMgdGhlIHN1YmplY3Qgb2Ygb3VyIG1lZXRpbmcuIn0=

This eliminated spaces and other troublesome characters.

Of course, you will need to decode it back inside your program, but this is relatively easy to do.

Answer (score 0):

The shell is removing the double quotes.
Instead, you could use single quotes in the json, e.g

```
{'networks':{'privateIP':'10.10.1.17','publicIP':'192.168.1.144'}}
```

Then parse it using:

```
ObjectMapper om = new ObjectMapper();
om.configure(JsonParser.Feature.ALLOW_SINGLE_QUOTES, true);
Networks n = om.readValue(args[0], Networks.class);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/bin/bash

JSON='
{
    "bbb":456,
    "aaaa": "SDFDS"
}
'
JSON=$(echo $JSON | sed s/\"/\\\"/g)
echo $JSON
java -Dmyparam="$JSON" Abc
```