# Java string how to replace " with \" to escape JSON?

Tags: java, regex, replace, escaping

I am trying to replace `"` with `\"` in Java, but all the slashes are getting very confusing. What is the proper way to replace `"` with `\"` in Java?

```
string.replaceAll("\"","\\"");
```

Comment: `string.replaceAll("\"","\\\\\"");`

Comment: Why don't you just use a JSON library instead? Don't reinvent the wheel, probably badly... (This isn't a judgement on your coding abilities - just that unless your primary task is building a JSON library, you're unlikely to do as good a job of it as those whose primary task *is* building a JSON library.)

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3020094/how-should-i-escape-strings-in-json

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are going to replace literals then don't use `replaceAll` but `replace`.

Reason for this is that `replaceAll` uses regex syntax which means that some characters will be treated specially like `+` `*` `\` `(` `)` and to make them literals you will need to escape them. `replace` adds escaping mechanism for you automatically, so instead of

```
replaceAll("\"", "\\\\\"")
```

you can write

```
replace("\"", "\\\"");
```

which is little less confusing.

Comment: Is this specific to windows?

Comment: @Arun No, this code should behave same in all OS.

Answer (score -1):

Try to use char:

```
public void bsp(){
  //34 = " ; 92 = \
  String replace = "\"";
  String replace2 = "\\";
  text.replace(replace.charAt(0),replace2.charAt(0));
}
```

Comment: You should try this approach first before posting it as answer (hint: `char` can be also considered as integer).

Answer (score -2):

```
string.replaceAll("\"", "\\\"");
```

Let's explain:
`"\""` : is a string with `\"` an escaped `"` char
`"\\\""`: is a string with a `\\` an escaped `\` char and a `\"` an escapd `"` char

Comment: This will not work. ``\`` is also special character in replacement part so you also need to escape it there (just like in regex).