# gson.fromJson return null values

Tags: java, json, object, gson

This is My JSON String : `"{'userName' : 'Bachooo'}"`

Converting JSON String to **LoginVO** logic is:

```
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().excludeFieldsWithoutExposeAnnotation().create();
LoginVO loginFrom  = gson.fromJson(jsonInString, LoginVO.class);
System.out.println("userName " + loginFrom.getUserName()); // output null
```

My **LoginVO.class** is:

```
public class LoginVO {

 private String userName;
 private String password;

 public String getUserName()
 {
    return userName;
 }
 public void setUserName(String userName)
 {
    this.userName = userName;
 }
 public String getPassword()
 {
    return password;
 }
 public void setPassword(String password)
 {
    this.password = password;
 }

}
```

Note I am using **jdk 1.8.0_92**

Output of loginForm.getUserName() is `NULL` instead of `"Bachooo"` any idea about this issue?

Comment: And what happens if you only use `Gson gson = new Gson()`?

Comment: if i only use Gson gson = new Gson()
Infinity loop at recursive calling com.google.gson.internal.$Gson$Types.resolve($Gson$Types.java:375)

Comment: what `excludeFieldsWithoutExposeAnnotation` says? "only expose fields that are annotated and ignore the rest "

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How should I escape strings in JSON?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3020094/how-should-i-escape-strings-in-json)

Comment: ^ i.e. single quotes are not valid JSON.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Since you are setting `excludeFieldsWithoutExposeAnnotation()` configuration on the `GsonBuilder` you must put `@Expose` annotation on those fields you want to serialize/deserialize.

So in order for `excludeFieldsWithoutExposeAnnotation()` to serialize/deserialize your fields you must add that annotation:

```
@Expose
private String userName;
@Expose
private String password;
```

Or, you could remove `excludeFieldsWithoutExposeAnnotation()` from the `GsonBuilder`.

Comment: Thanks man its work 100% all I need @Expose To my variable i need to initialized.

Comment: Or the other option is to just say new GsonBuilder().create() if you dont have access to edit the class

Answer (score 0):

Adding what resolved this for me.
So in my API following gson implementation was getting used:

```
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().setFieldNamingPolicy(FieldNamingPolicy.LOWER_CASE_WITH_UNDERSCORES).create();
```

I had to use the same implementation in my test, before which gson was failing to parse attributes.

So in essence check how your gson is configured in api/handler, and use same configuration in your test.

Answer (score -2):

Try like this, please. Here is the example class:

```
class AngilinaJoile {
    private String name;

    // setter

    // getter  
}
```

And here is how you deserialize it with Gson:

```
Gson gson = new Gson();  
String jsonInString = "{'name' : 'kumaresan perumal'}";
AngilinaJoile angel = gson.fromJson(jsonInString, AngilinaJoile.class);
```