# Facebook Graph API: The "Next" link for "Paging" is not working

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, paging

I'm getting the feed from a page through the Facebook Graph API. At the end there is a link given, in order to retrieve the next page of the feed, as shown here (I removed my access token):

```
   "paging": {
      "previous": "https://graph.facebook.com/v2.8/14408401557/feed?fields=from,message,link,created_time,type,name,id,comments.limit\u0025280\u002529.summary\u002528true\u002529,shares,reactions.limit\u0025280\u002529.summary\u002528true\u002529&limit=100&since=1483025111&access_token=XXX|XXX&__paging_token=enc_AdABZBt6ZC7DctahZAsXG9wOUghwu8tMLYo1ZAlMdLcVCwa8VqVjBEsZABFiLRSVlA96xTQzKkrnd2ALIlGrGLhZALSum7&__previous=1",
      "next": "https://graph.facebook.com/v2.8/14408401557/feed?fields=from,message,link,created_time,type,name,id,comments.limit\u0025280\u002529.summary\u002528true\u002529,shares,reactions.limit\u0025280\u002529.summary\u002528true\u002529&limit=100&access_token=XXX|XXX&__paging_token=enc_AdBOFdepWf3pcZBDLiV0r00WXJZA8qN7iYCZCzrwSoZCxYuKnHvXVUyCp35KCz4CW35p0gsmQV3Vzs5xKXe16QyCKMEN"
```

If I try to use the given url, I get the following error:

```
   "error": {
      "message": "Syntax error \"Expected \")\", got end of string\" at character 171: from,message,link,created_time,type,name,id,comments.limit(u0025280\\u002529.summary\\u002528true\\u002529,shares,reactions.limit\\u0025280\\u002529.summary\\u002528true\\u002529",
      "type": "OAuthException",
      "code": 2500,
      "fbtrace_id": "Dxf6QrEjBl6"
   }
```

Does anybody know why?

Answer (score 1):

They seem to be encoded fine as output of JSON.  But my guess is you are not decoding them before using.  e.g.

comments.limit\u0025280\u002529.summary\u002528true\u002529

e.g. if you replace manually it works

comments.limit%280%29.summary%28true%29

See this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/3020108/1542667 for an explanation of JSON encoding of strings, \u0025 is just '%'

Comment: This is the right answer, despite not being marked so. OP is trying to use raw JSON, instead of decoding it first.