# While returning the string it adds extra slash to the string

Tags: java, json, string, spring-mvc, gson

I am writing a rest api.All things are set and woking fine.
My controller :

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/getDetails", method = RequestMethod.POST, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
@ResponseBody
public String getDetails(@RequestBody String jsonInput) {
    LOGGER.info("<------------------------ from Date   :" + jsonInput );
    System.out.println("resp ="+apiService.getDetails(jsonInput));
    return apiService.getDetails(jsonInput);

}
```

When I sysout the response on console it will print normal string like -

```
[{"name": "abc","vendor": "abc df"}]
```

But I get the respnse with extra slash. All double quote is replaced by \".

```
"[{\"name\":\"abc\",\"vendor\":\"abc df\"}]"
```

Please help !. Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is expected behavior. The `\ `  escapes special characters so that they can be printed. Inspecting a `Map()` object might reveal a similar outcome.

Comment: i have found a more but subtle question , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3020094/how-should-i-escape-strings-in-json

Comment: Already done this,when converting string to object to json
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().disableHtmlEscaping().create();
  String jsonRes = gson.toJson(resp);

Comment: @j.seashell : I know this is the expected, but I am searching the way to remove slash.

Comment: When I hit the api from postman tool ,the response looks weird.

Comment: Why are you getBillingDetails in print and getDetails in return?

Comment: What is "looks weird"? You should NOT do what you're trying to do. JSON specifications require `"` to be escaped. Not to mention, how is Javascript supposed to interpret this response if the quotes aren't escaped?

Comment: @Christopher Schneider : I got it. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

This is expected so the object can be reconstructed later on. The "\" escapes the quote. You can replace the "\" with a empty string:

```
@ResponseBody
public String getDetails(@RequestBody String jsonInput) {
    LOGGER.info("<------------------------ from Date   :" + jsonInput );
    System.out.println("resp ="+apiService.getBillingDetails(jsonInput));
    return apiService.getDetails(jsonInput).replace("\\", "");

}
```

Comment: No. It's not working. :(
This is what I am telling when I print the sysout it printing the normal JSON.
But I am getting extra slash in postman tool or any other rest api hitting tool.

Answer (score 0):

use

```
string ResponseString = Regex.Unescape(oldString);
```

This should remove all the unnecessary escape characters.

Answer (score 0):

I recently came across the same issue. I was trying to fix it for a long time and finally found the fix and what I was doing wrong.
I was framing multiple json strings using Jackson library and storing it into a list.

When I tried to return the jsonList as such to my controller, I was getting the ouput printed on my postman API with double quotes and backslashes, although I did not have this issue while printing to console.

When I tried to return my list as String to the controller fixed my issue.

```
jsonString = frameJsonKeyValuePair(header, dataList);
if (jsonString != null)
        jsonStringList.add(jsonString);
}
return jsonStringList.toString();
```