# JSON : Escape Double Quotes within JSON String

Tags: java, json, regex

I have a JSON string like this :

```
 {
       "serviceName":"Data file "%s" was deleted successfully.",
       "serviceInstance":"esm-session-service"
     }
```

I am trying to map above JSON to object using ObjectMapper as below:

```
Message messageObject = objectMapper.readValue(messageJson, Message.class);
```

Below is stack trace output:

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException: Unexpected character ('%' (code 37)): was expecting comma to separate Object entries
 at [Source: (String)"{"serviceName":"\"Data file \""%s"serviceInstance":"esm-session-service"}r""; line: 1, column: 33]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParser._constructError(JsonParser.java:1804)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.base.ParserMinimalBase._reportError(ParserMinimalBase.java:663)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.base.ParserMinimalBase._reportUnexpectedChar(ParserMinimalBase.java:561)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.json.ReaderBasedJsonParser._skipComma(ReaderBasedJsonParser.java:2271)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.json.ReaderBasedJsonParser.nextFieldName(ReaderBasedJsonParser.java:892)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.vanillaDeserialize(BeanDeserializer.java:295)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserialize(BeanDeserializer.java:151)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._readMapAndClose(ObjectMapper.java:4001)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.java:2992)
    at com.test.json.TestJsonObjectConversion.main(TestJsonObjectConversion.java:77)
```

I know problem is with **"%s"** in the JSON, I am not able to find any way to escape quotes in only "%s".

I am expecting below JSON:

```
{
  "serviceName":"Data file \"%s\" was deleted successfully.",
  "serviceInstance":"esm-session-service"
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The problem is the source of your JSON string.  So, whence are you getting this JSON string?

Comment: Except %s  is there  more possibilities to add escape sequence ?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen, I am getting this JSON from elastic search.

Comment: @PrashantPalve, as of now I got "%s", but it is possible that I may get any string with double quotes in this JSON

Comment: I wouldn’t put *any* effort into trying to parse invalid JSON. Fix the *actual error* instead.

Comment: If you are a consumer, you can/must do nothing to correct it, open a ticket for producer instead

Comment: Fix at source - if cant then refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3020094/how-should-i-escape-strings-in-json

Answer (score 0):

The problem is stated as receiving an invalid JSON string from Elastic Search where double quotes are not escaped.

If you cannot find a correction by Elastic Search (looking for the latest version), a **patch** is in order:

Assuming key value pairs occupy a single line:

Since java 9:

```
String json = ...;
json = json.replaceAll(":\\s*\"(.*)\"",
        (m) -> {
            String value = m.group(1);
            value = value.replaceAll("(?!\\)\"", "\\\\\");
            return ":\"" + value + "\"";
        });
```

This will fill `value` with the longest sequence between double quotes.
The negative lookahead `(?!\\)` checks that no backslash already precedes an inner double quote.

Maybe better would be to overall escape the string value by Apache Common Text [StringEscapeUtils](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-text/apidocs/org/apache/commons/text/StringEscapeUtils.html#escapeJson-java.lang.String-):

```
json = json.replaceAll(":\\s*\"(.*)\"",
        (m) -> ":\"" + StringEscapeUtils.escapeJson(m.group(1)) + "\"");
```

Prior to java 9 one would need a loop for the regex replace.
If the key-value pairs are not on one line (like the value containing newlines) again the regex needs to do multiline, DOT_ALL.

The resulting JSON string can be passed, maybe via a StringReader.