# Newtonsoft.JSON Cannot parse JSON with file path as value

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I'm using Newtonsoft.JSON to parse JSON files.

This is a JSON file I'm using:

```
[
  {
    "FilePath"    : "C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\dummyFile.txt",
    "DisplayName" : "Dummy File"
  }
]
```

And I get the following error saying that it couldn't properly parse "\U" (from C:**\U**sers.....) at

```
JsonTextReader reader = new JsonTextReader(new StringReader(File.ReadAllText(gamelist, Encoding.Unicode)));
while (reader.Read())
{
  //do stuff here
```

Comment: Looks like it needs to be escaped. C:\\Users\\Administrator etc.

Comment: This is **not** valid json

Comment: Paste the JSON into any parser and it will tell you it's not valid (e.g. http://json.parser.online.fr)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3020108/1887802

Comment: thanks @SteveJ , worked.

Answer (score 1):

@Hyblocker, replace the backslash as it is creating the problem.
Below code works

```
//Read the json from gamelist file
var fileData = File.ReadAllText(gamelist);
//replace "\" with "\\"
fileData = fileData.Replace("\\", "\\\\");
//parse it
JsonTextReader reader = new JsonTextReader(new StringReader(fileData));
while (reader.Read())
{
       //code
}
```

Comment: While this might work for the simple JSON shown above, it is not a robust solution as the `DisplayName` property might contain slashes that don't need to be escaped. The only valid solution is to fix the source file.

Comment: @DavidG, I agree with you. Even Newtonsoft has a limitation with special character.