# How to use the copyright and trademark symbols in REST API?

Tags: java, rest, web-services

How to use copyright symbol and trad mark symbol in rest api call (I need to pass  one of the Json parameter )

I need to get it in Java code and save the values in DB .

Anyone have an idea on this?

Comment: So you are experiencing problems with text being sent in the JSON payload to your rest service? what format is the JSON payload in? do you have a sample?

Comment: Its in UTF-8 format

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use special characters you will to escape it.

Please read answer from this topic:

[How should I escape strings in JSON?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3020094/how-should-i-escape-strings-in-json)

Or you can use this service (for manual inputs):

https://www.freeformatter.com/json-escape.html

Or any modern JSON library with escaping support.

Comment: I am using com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonGenrator and i enable ansii escape but while enter  in JSOn string its giving error

Comment: is there any possiblity ?