# why do we escape Json? In what case we want to escape it and what we don't?

Tags: json

I have seen some questions regarding how we escape/unescape Json, but I am wondering why do we need/want it. I did a google search but didn't find answers.

In what case we want to escape it and what we don't?

Comment: You need it as in all other cases: to distinguish between the JSON format itself and the data stored within the values

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3020094/how-should-i-escape-strings-in-json for more details